# How to show/hide fields in edit or read mode in ODK aggregate

Tags: odk, odk-xform

I am working with ODK aggregate and I want to know if it is possible to show or hide fields only if the user has open the form in Edit Mode or Read mode.
To explain what I want, I would say that there are two Modes in ODK collect:

- Edit mode: When the user clicks "Fill Blank Form" and starts to give values to every field of the form, one-by-one.
- Read mode: When the user clicks "Edit Saved Form" of "View Send form" and only sees the values that he's given to every field.

I was wondering if it possible to hide a field only if the user is seeing the form in edit mode.
As an example lets see the following "calculate" field. I want to show that field only if the user is in Read mode, So it would hide when the user is filling the form. It is possible to do that on ODK aggregate?

[image]